# WebAudio API and cordova still play audio on exit

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, web-audio-api

I'm using the howerjs audio library for my game that I am creating with Cordova.  How can I disable the entire app or pause the audio when the user leaves the app?  Right now the music continues to play. Is there a hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach a function to the [pause event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/cordova/events/events.html#pause). This method is thrown by Cordova when the application moves to the background.

```
document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);

function onPause() {
    // audio.pause();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped me alot!

Comment: upon further investigation, this does not work with admob pro plugin or a splash screen.  Both of them cause the app to "pause"